# Everytime I try to reorganize the columns in this data set using Pandas in Python, all values turn Nan. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan, reindex

As part of an assignment, Im trying to reorganize the columns in a way that the types (of coffee) are in alphabetical order. I implemented the following code, and it does work:

```
#Rearrange the names of the Coffees so they are in alphabetical order
Reorganized = ["Channel", "Region", "Arabica", "Cappuccino", "Espresso", "Latte", "Lungo"]
BeanFileCleaned = BeanFileCleaned.reindex(columns=Reorganized)

BeanFileCleaned
```

However, when I run the file again, all the values in the table turn Nan and for some reason, the rows also have the same name as the columns (there are a lot of rows, so this shouldnt happen).

How do I fix this? Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Edit: Forgot to add, this is what the result looks like:

[image]

Comment: `newDF = BeanFileCleaned [Reorganized]` ?

Comment: That would imply that these are not the column headers you have. What is the output from `print(BeanFileCleaned.columns)`?

Comment: @JoranBeasley I did that, I got the same result

Comment: @HenryEcker The output from using that just results in the names of the columns. It doesnt do anything else

Comment: Right. But reindexing columns returning nans means that you do not have those columns to begin with. You cannot reorder columns that do not exist. Hence why I asked what your columns are _before_ you try to reindex...

Comment: @HenryEcker Well, in that case, the columns before I tried to reindex were as follows: Channel Region Robusta Arabica Espresso Lungo Latte Cappuccino

Comment: The output from `BeanFileCleaned.columns` is what is needed. Because `Index(['Channel', 'Region'], dtype='object')` and `Index(['Channel ', 'Region '], dtype='object')` are different. If there is extra whitespace, or different characters, etc, etc.

Comment: @HenryEcker The output of `BeanFileCleaned.columns` if it helps, is `Index(['Channel', 'Region', 'Arabica', 'Cappuccino', 'Espresso', 'Latte', 'Lungo'],
      dtype='object')`

Comment: Okay so I'm now quite confused. Your DataFrame index _and_ columns are identical. Your columns are already in the correct order, but you're using `reindex` to order them? And somehow you're getting `nan` values?

Comment: @HenryEcker Im just trying to use `reindex` in order to rearrange the columns. But somehow it's making the rows get the same name while resulting in `nan` values.

Comment: It's pretty hard for me to communicate what is happening, but Ill take everything you said into consideration. It's probably me missing something in the function or just using the wrong one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that BeanFileCleaned is a pandas dataframe, you are probably looking for something like this.

```py
#Rearrange the names of the Coffees so they are in alphabetical order
Reorganized = ["Channel", "Region", "Arabica", "Cappuccino", "Espresso", "Latte", "Lungo"]
Reorganized = sorted(Reogranized)
BeanFileCleaned = BeanFileCleaned[Reorganized]
```

If you have extra columns you want to append to the end you can do it like

```py
all_columns = BeanFileCleaned.columns

#Rearrange the names of the Coffees so they are in alphabetical order
Reorganized = ["Channel", "Region", "Arabica", "Cappuccino", "Espresso", "Latte", "Lungo"]
Reorganized = sorted(Reogranized)
Reorganized_set = set(Reorganized)
rest_columns = [column for column in all_columns if column not in Reorganized_set]

BeanFileCleaned = BeanFileCleaned[Reorganized + rest_columns]
```

Comment: I had to do some editing on my part, but your suggestion worked . For anyone in the future , my final working code was the following:                                                                                                                                              ```#Rearrange the names of the Coffees so they are in alphabetical order
AlphabeticalOrder = ["Channel", "Region", "Arabica", "Cappuccino", "Espresso", "Latte", "Lungo"]
BeanFileCleaned = BeanFileCleaned.reindex(columns=AlphabeticalOrder)
BeanFileCleaned = BeanFileCleaned[AlphabeticalOrder]```